# Key takeaways in German in a presentation

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

I am preparing a presentation for a public talk on a startup conference in german. I'm on the last slide with the key messages of my presentation, the key takeaways.

What's the proper german translation for "key takeaways"? How should I name that slide?

Zusammenfassung is not the right word because it is not a summary. It's more about the learning points of my talk.

Comment: @infinitezero Public talk on a startup conference.

Comment: I thought it is *tl;dr* even in German? ;-) (and should be on top)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica "tl;dr" is very much a modern expression. I'm sure if I wrote "tl;dr" to my mom, she would not understand.

Comment: @MechMK1 Well, the event is most likely not catering to your mom, and if it was, she'd now the expression :-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Es kommt stark darauf an, welchen Sprachstil du verwendest. Ist die Präsentation eher förmlich oder eher locker? Auch der Inhalt der Präsentation kann einen Einfluss darauf haben, welchen Begriff du für *key takeaways* einsetzen kannst.

Hier eine Auswahl möglicher Ausdrücke:

- Schlussfolgerungen:
- Kernpunkte:
- Zusammenfassung:
- Merkpunkte:
- Zum Merken:
- Fazit:
- Summa summarum:
- Jetzt zum Mitschreiben:
- Ergo:
- Wir merken uns:

<sup>(Die Liste ist ungeordnet.)</sup>

Comment: Danke für die Liste. Kernpunkte passt am besten!

Answer (score 6):

In spoken language, you would probably use a construction such as:

> Und das sollten Sie aus diesem Vortrag mitnehmen:

Concerning an actual title for the slide, that is slightly more difficult as there is not one single universally accepted phrasing. However, I would suggest:

- Kernpunkte
- Take Home Messages

(Yes, that second one is in English; many audiences will understand what is meant, though.)

Comment: “Take home message” is especially common in an academic setting.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the summary or Zusammenfassung of a talk, that is shown in the end of a presentation should contain the key takeaways, so you can use the word here.

You can also use the English "key points", if your audience is likely to be familiar with the term.

Comment: The observation that the audience will not only be familiar but appreciate and bask in English buzz words is a good one. So in a talk on a startup conference the translation of *key takeaways* is *key takeaways*.

Answer (score 2):

Am Ende eine Präsentation, wie Du sie beschreibst, würde das Präsentationsfazit kommen. Generell wird diese Seite auch einfach "Fazit" genannt. Wenn deine Präsentation am Anfang eine Übersicht über den Inhalt hat, dann kannst Du diese Seite dort auch als Fazit auflisten. "Schlussfolgerung" oder "Zusammenfassung" kann auch verwendet werden, jedoch ist "Fazit" universeller anwendbar und eine bessere Wahl, die jeder versteht. Ausdrücke wie "Jetzt zum Mitschreiben" oder "Wir merken uns" sind nicht gebräuchlich und würde ich vermeiden.

Mit dem Scuhbegriff *präsentation fazit* findest Du im Internet viele Artikel zu dem Thema.

Comment: Fazit ist aber Einzahl.

Comment: 1. Fazit beschreibt in meinen Augen aber eher eine Zusammenfassung des gesagten anstelle einer Botschaft zum Mitnehmen; 2. ist es hier üblich, Fragen, die auf Englisch gestellt sind, auch auf Englisch zu beantworten (und umgekehrt).